# Two power sources on gas furnace?

Tags: furnace

I have recently purchased a home that has a high efficiency furnace in it. The previous owner had done some demo on an interior wall leaving a 2x4 with a switch on it. As well there is the usual turn off switch above the furnace on the ceiling. You can see the second switch connecting to the furnace just below the condensate pump. What would this be for?

top wire leads to roof switch bottom to wall switch

[image]

roof switch
[image: roof switch]

wall switch
[image]

Comment: What would *what* be for?

Comment: The second switch and power lead.

Comment: In the third picture, the Romex is not secured correctly.  No electrician did that.  Where does that cable go?

Comment: It would’ve been done properly originally, but the wall it was attached to had been demolished due to Flood. This is the remnants. Plan to rebuild wall and attach properly. Just not sure what it’s for. Goes into ceiling and maybe to thermostat?

Comment: I don't know what "the usual turnoff switch" is. No furnace I've seen has more than the single disconnect on the wall. Please provide details.

Comment: Do the flex conduit and thermostat wire both enter that black box?

Comment: Is that a label reading "Export" hanging below the left-hand switch? Is it supplied from the same source/breaker as the right-hand switch?

Comment: Seems like a great time to consult the manual.  Do you have the manual?  Can you provide a make/model to find online?

Comment: @SteveWellens I get your point, and I won't paint with too broad a brush here, but if you saw some of the things that I've seen done by "electricians" then you may have a different opinion.  Twice I've found hot NM cable just dangling (once 3' off the ground where a child could grab...this is in a house, not a factory).  If you find a "good" electrician then pay him whatever he wants (or she).  Otherwise, that's why I do most of my work myself.

Comment: A 2 switch setup This is quite a common setup in my area. I probably have done close to 100 in a similar way. The power to the furnace comes in on 1 switch. The second switch may be a fan on over ride switch just pulling in the fan motor the thermostat still controls the call for heat. Without knowing more on how the furnace is wired this would be my guess and as I say fairly common.

Comment: @isherwood the turnoff switch is pretty common around here, its a disconnect from system power to do maintenance rather than flipping the breaker, the export tag is for the ducting, and no the second flex conduit enters below the box into the lower portion of furnace.

Comment: @EdBeal was wondering if it was a fan switch, like to keep fan on during summer without the heat coming on?

Comment: Yes that is one of the reasons I install them it really improves air quality if you have electrostatic filters and circulates the air keeping the house room temps similar. I also use in winter to circulate wood heat really saves on the gas Bill.

Comment: @user1881482 Every thermostat I've seen has a switch to turn on the fan without the furnace or AC running.

Comment: @SteveWellens yes seen that on the thermostat itself, but this is a wall switch independent of the thermostat

Comment: @steve wellens   A fan control switch is not common on a furnace 2 wire thermostat. The secondary reason to have a manual switch is the thermostat ones usually are digitally controlled every power bump burns battery life where the separate switch doesn't affect battery power at all. The fact you haven’t seen a stat without a switch shows limited experience as prior to the 80’s thermostat control was very rare and became more popular with combination heating and cooling systems, the most common thermostat in the world even in the early 2k years was the 2 wire Honeywell, maybe not today though.

Comment: What make and model is the furnace in question?

Comment: @EdBeal  I used to work at Honeywell and the two wire mercury thermostat (which built the company) was pure genius.  It does so much..so elegantly.